# JS: Object iteration fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

In my JS, I have an object called box_object.
It looks like this:

```
({  id:"3",
    text:"this is a box object",
    connection_parent:["1", "2"],
    connection_child:["5", "6"],
    connectiondata_child:{
        0:{id:"5", linepoint:"bottom"},
        1:{id:"6", linepoint:"bottom"}},
    connectiondata_parent:{
        0:{id:"1", linepoint:"top"},
        1:{id:"2", linepoint:"top"}}
})
```

Now, I want to add some position values to box_object.connectiondata_parent. Using jQuery I can use the .each() method. So I tried it, but it failed.
In my function I do the following:

```
$(box_object.connectiondata_parent).each(function(it, obj){
    if(typeof(obj[it]) != "undefined" && obj[it].linepoint == "top"){
        var point_position_top = new Object();
        point_position_top.left = startingpoint_left;
        point_position_top.top = startingpoint_top;
        obj[it].position = point_position_top;
    }else if(typeof(obj[it]) != "undefined" && obj[it].linepoint == "bottom"){
        var point_position_bottom = new Object();
        point_position_bottom.left = startingpoint_left;
        point_position_bottom.top = startingpoint_bottom;
        obj[it].position = point_position_bottom;
    }else{}
});
```

After the function my box_object looks like this:

```
({ id:"3",
   text:"this is third box",
   connection_parent:["1", "2"],
   connection_child:["5", "6"],
   connectiondata_child:{
      0:{id:"5", linepoint:"bottom"},
      1:{id:"6", linepoint:"bottom"}},
   connectiondata_parent:{
      0:{id:"1", linepoint:"top", position:{left:500, top:104}},
      1:{id:"2", linepoint:"top"}}
})
```

It seems it only writes the values to the first "value". Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/) by [Karl Swedberg](http://www.learningjquery.com/), on `$(selector).each()`

> This should be used for DOM elements.
>   For normal objects or arrays, use
>   [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Maybe then that is what giving you a problem.

Comment: Thank you! Just for the record: `$.each(box_object.connectiondata_parent, function(it, obj){...}` and then use obj instead of obj[it].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a framework for the each functionality, the following code sample will iterate over the proper entries in the nested elements and perform the requested transformations.

```
function assert(cond, msg) {
  if (!cond) {
    throw msg + " ... failed";
  }
}

// assumed globals
var startingpoint_left   = 500;
var startingpoint_top    = 104;
var startingpoint_bottom =  50; // never shown in sample but referenced                                                         
var idx;

for (idx in box_object.connectiondata_parent) {
  if (box_object.connectiondata_parent.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
    if (box_object.connectiondata_parent[idx]) {
      box_object.connectiondata_parent[idx].position = {
        "left": startingpoint_left,
        "top":  box_object.connectiondata_parent[idx].linepoint === "top" ? startingpoint_top : startingpoint_bottom
      };
    }
  }
}

assert(box_object.connectiondata_parent[0].position.top  === 104, "index 0 top ");
assert(box_object.connectiondata_parent[0].position.left === 500, "index 0 left");
assert(box_object.connectiondata_parent[1].position.top  === 104, "index 1 top ");
assert(box_object.connectiondata_parent[1].position.left === 500, "index 1 top ");
```